# Orthonormal basis

Tags: functional-analysis

> Suppose $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal sequence in a Hilbert space $H$. Then $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis if and only if $h=0$ given $h \in H$ and $h \perp e_n$ for all $n$.

My question concerns the proof of the forward direction; that is, if $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis and $h \perp e_n$, then $h=0$.

The proof in my textbook suggests proof by contrapositive: Suppose $h \not=0$ and note as above that $h \perp e_n$. Then $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \cup \{\frac h{\|h\|}\}$ is an orthonormal set.

Now how does $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \cup \{\frac h{\|h\|}\}$ become an orthonormal set based on this? I do notice, though, as a result that $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset \{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \cup \{\frac h{\|h\|}\}$, which would make $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ *not* an orthonormal basis by this reasoning, completing the contrapositive proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $h \ne 0$ and $h \perp e_n$ for all $n$, then $\left\lVert \frac{h}{\lVert h \rVert} \right\rVert = 1$ and $\frac{h}{\lVert h \rVert} \perp e_n$ for all $n$. Thus the set $X = \{ e_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup \left\{ \frac{h}{\lVert h \rVert} \right\}$ satisfies the necessary conditions to be a normal set, namely that if $x \in X$ then $\lVert x \rVert = 1$ and if $x \ne y \in X$ then $x \perp y$. Moreover, $X$ is not a basis since it strictly contains the orthonormal set $\{ e_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

Comment: How did we obtain $\left\|\frac h{\|h\|} \right\|=1$?

Comment: Since $\frac{1}{\lVert h \rVert}$ is a positive scalar you can pull it out to obtain $$\left\lVert \frac{h}{\lVert h \rVert} \right\rVert = \frac{1}{\lVert h \rVert} \lVert h \rVert = 1$$

Comment: And is the fact that $\frac h{\|h\|} \perp e_n$ due to our hypothesis of $h \perp e_n$ (when working with proving the contrapositive)?

Comment: Yes, multiplying by a (non-zero) scalar doesn't change orthogonality.